# A coffee to go....( for syntax experts)

Tags: nouns, syntactic-analysis, complements

Could the infinitive phrase "to go" be a complement of the noun phrase "a coffee"?

Comment: "To go" is a fixed phrase and functions as the predicate of a [_Whiz_-Deleted relative clause](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a15299%20whiz%20deletion), like _a burger with everything, a politician on the take, one ring to rule them all_. Whether you should call that a "complement" is a matter between you and your confessor. I wouldn't, personally -- I use the term ***[Complement](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/complements.pdf)*** for a type of noun clause. This excludes relative clauses of all kinds, since they modify nouns, rather than functioning as noun phrases.

Comment: I'm not sure it is a complement, merely because *to go* seems to occur freely with many other NPs, *a donut to go*, *a veggie-burger to go* etc etc. Probably more of a regular NP postmodifier. Some will probably say it's a case of Whiz deletion *a coffee which is to go*. No idea if that's correct though ...

Comment: and as if by magic! while I was just writing it! I'll take it that is is a case of Whiz deletion then ... :)

Comment: I don't see anything syntactically "unusual" here. It seems to me *"Six coffees to go, please"* and *"We'd like one pizza to share"* are the same general form as *"I bought this food to eat tonight"*.

Comment: I'm not sure it is a complement, merely because the word is used by grammarians with conflicting meanings (as John Lawler implies).

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's a bit unusual isn't it because you share the pizza and eat the food, but you don't *go* the coffee? Also there seems to be a kind of anaphoric gap or deletion in the other cases *We'd like one pizza (for us) to share (**it**)* *I bought this food (for me) to eat (**it**) tonight*. But not *I'm buying this coffee (for me) to go (**it**)*. The first ones are like infinitives of purpose, it seems to me. But I'm not sure that the *to go* one is?

Comment: @Araucaria Surely that would just be the intransitive counterpart to those: “I’m buying this coffee _(for it)_ to go”? (Although, to be honest, who would want their coffee to go? What’s the point of buying it if it’s just going to do a bunk and leave you as coffeeless as you were before you bought it?)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Could well be, I suppose. I don't know ... :)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Actually, although I'm not discounting it outright, that gap doesn't seem to be able to co-refer anaphorically (can't work out how to put that) with the item in the object position. * *I punched him to fall down* It seems to automatically refer to the subject when it's an infinitive of purpose ... :)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet yes, should be a coffee to stay!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, who would want a coffee to go? To go where? As you know we don't use the expression. We say 'coffee to take away'. Indeed any establishment that offers meals that are wrapped up for outside consumption is called 'a take-away'. But it has nothing to do with subtraction.

Comment: @WS2 Who is 'we'? The expression is not uncommon hereabouts (especially in certain fast food outlets), and is on the increase according to this [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=coffee+to+go&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccoffee%20to%20go%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @FF 'We'd like six coffees to go' and 'We'd like six policemen to go' have the same surface structure.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Were my wife agreeable I'd go and live in France to escape the exposure to this cultural deformity.

Comment: @Edwin: I suppose by "surface structure" you mean they both contain the words **to go**, but I see little similarity in terms of *syntactic* structure there. On the other hand, Araucaria apparently sees some significant difference between *"A coffee to go [**with me**, because I'm not going to drink it here]"* and *"A pizza to share [**between** us, because we're too poor/not hungry enough to want one each]"*. Those seem pretty similar to me - I think the exact prepositions used in the "extended" forms are largely irrelevant.

Comment: @FF Yes; for analysis, paraphrases can be helpful. // With 'a coffee to go / a pizza to share', there _is_ a difference, as 'share' is a shorthand for 'for us to share / to be shared by us', but 'go' is intransitive (hereabouts). 'A coffee to take' might be expected.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't really see a PP being ellipted in infinitives of purpose, like the ones you mention, just a direct object.

Comment: Snow: how are you defining 'complement' here?

Comment: A complement is something which is licensed by its head. Some phrases need something in addition to the Head in
order to express a complete meaning:)

Comment: Using the word 'license' here to mean demand rather than allow. Wikipedia is more cautious when [discussing valency theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(linguistics)): 'The basic analysis of the syntax and semantics of clauses relies heavily on the distinction between arguments and adjuncts. The clause predicate, which is often a content verb, demands certain arguments. That is, the arguments are necessary in order to complete the meaning of the verb.' As J Lawler says, the term 'complement' is considered by some inappropriate for noun modifiers.

Comment: You may be interested to know that 'coffee to go' is not used in the UK. The expression used here is 'coffee to take away'. The UK expression is thus more literal but the NA expression is more concise.

Comment: @Araucaria - I think you do "go the coffee", eventually.

Comment: I understand complement in the sense used by @Snow -- it completes the meaning of its head.  The paradigmatic complement is the direct object of a verb, and other complements can be understood by analogy: over *the river*,  drink *coffee*, father *of the bride*, fond *of ice cream*.  "To go" is merely a modifier, and specifically, "coffee to go" is packaged in a styrofoam cup, suitable for carrying away before drinking.

Comment: In Mexican Spanish _to go_ comes out _para llevar_ 'for (to) carry', which refers to an object rather than the subject of _to go_. These relative infinitives are full of such variation; and I always suspect a hidden modal, like the unheard _should_ in _the man to see_ or _the way to do it_.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I can't see a problem with that.

However, it is normally unnecessary - it makes no difference to the server if it is to go or you will drink it in the shop - it typically is "to go". If, however, it is a shop that offers ceramic cups for non-takeaway, you do need to specify.

Comment: Thank you Tim...so that's only a post-modifier, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, and often not required.

Comment: I've been studying syntax for about 1 year and I find it very interesting, I've got lots of questions and I hope you'll be able to help me :) Thanks!!!!

Comment: By 'only a post-modifier' I assume that you mean 'and not a venerable complement'. The trouble is that there isn't an agreed definition of the term (Fowler spends time contrasting usages); what you read even in CGEL isn't gospel. It's one (usually good) approach.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, user79940, If you're a linguistics student nowadays, chances are what you mean is something that's specially licenced by another item. So probably what the OP wants to know is whether *to go* is something that we'd regard as being specially licensed by the noun *coffee* (in the same way that certain prepositions are licensed by certain verbs eg: *ask for*) But, I agree that the term's not used uniformly. I guess User'll have to let us know what they mean?

Comment: In many coffee shops, they will serve you coffee in a ceramic cup if you plan to stay and drink it, and a disposable cup otherwise.

Comment: @Petershor very good point! Edited to include.

Comment: @Araucaria From the fact that OP says 'so that's only a post-modifier?', I'd guess that he sees a complement as being grammatically non-omissible.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Not sure. Might be that if it's not specially licensed, then it's functioning as a kind of adjunct in NP, ie as a postmodifier. So 'only' here might mean either not licensed or wqually, just as you say, not obligatory. (Very few things we regard as complements really are obligatory imo)

Answer (score 0):

a coffee to go

is a noun group with coffee as head element and "a" and "to go" as sub-elements (or modifiers or attributes).

To-infinitives can be used as modifiers: I'd like a book to read. One could derive such a structure by using three sentences: I'd like a book - what for? - to read it.

The derivation of the fixed expression of coffee shops "coffee to go" is a bit difficult: The sense is a cup of coffee that you can take with you (you don't drink it in the shop). That the expression uses "to go" is a bit funny, but it is short and understandable: coffee to go with you (out of the shop).

I wouldn't use the term complement, as it is ambiguous. Mostly complement is used in connection with linking verbs. In "He is a doctor" "a doctor" is a subject complement.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your definition of *complement*. If you define a complement as anything that completes something then I guess you could call it a complement. I usually reserve *complement* for predicate nouns or adjectives, tho. I'd call this a post-modifier, ie, an adjectival phrase that occurs after the noun, similar to a prepositional phrase or a participial phrase.

Answer (score 0):

A **coffee to go is** like a *table to eat*.
It's a necessary qualifier that indicates purpose, suitability or reason.
It's necessary to avoid confusion or a mistake.

When I say: *We would like that table to eat*, it does not mean I want to eat the table. Neither do I wish for the table to start chewing on something. 
I'm asking for a menu and checking that the kitchen is open. If not, I will go somewhere else.

A "coffee to go" is a coffee that is for going (walking) and going (leaving) and going (not coming back).
It is *suitable* to go, portable and disposable.

It doesn't always work: I bought this *necklace to gift*.
We'd rather say that it is a present.

Comment: But OP asks (probably unwisely) '[Is it a] complement [of the noun]?'

Answer (score -2):

*You go for a coffee* or *you go to drink coffee*, but you do not say *you go a coffee*, so the phrase is a bit strange because of the collocations of the word *coffee* has no the verb *go*. *A coffee to drink* sounds better.

Comment: "To go" means that the coffee is provided in a form that may be conveniently removed from the establishment, vs being consumed on the premises.